# SQL Server queries to linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

How do I write the linq queries for the following procedure

```
create proc [dbo].[sp_remainUser]    
     @userid int
as       
begin
    select * 
    from userlog
    where 
        user_id not in (select followed_id 
                        from userfollowing 
                        where follower_id = @userid)
        and user_id not in (select follower_id 
                            from userfollowing 
                            where follower_id = @userid)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var userid = ....
var followed = db.userfollowing.Where(i => i.follower_id = userid).select(i=>i.followed_id ).ToList();
var follower = db.userfollowing.Where(i => i.follower_id = userid).select(i=>i.follower_id ).ToList();

var temp = db.userlog.where(i => followed.Contains(i.user_id) and followed.Contains(i.user_id));
var filteredList = temp.Except(followed).Except(follower);
```

You can't just type "!Contains" or "not Contains", so you have to do the Contains filter and the take the opposite, doing an Except on the original set.

Hope it is clear for you, ask if you need more info.